# Search and alter text with python in a svg file

Tags: python, xml, svg

I've a SVG file created with Inkscape, now in the svg file is some text i try to alter but how?
The svg looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <svg
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
  width="1480"
  height="800"
  version="1.1"
  id="svg4184"
  sodipodi:docname="2017-05-03_heizung2.svg"
  inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371">
  ...
  <g
   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
   inkscape:label="05_CURVES"
   id="g4182"
   transform="translate(0,-322.51962)"
   style="display:inline">
   ...
   <text
     xml:space="preserve"
     style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:37.33333206px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
     x="82.288353"
     y="920.41907"
     id="temp-bu"><tspan
       sodipodi:role="line"
       id="tspan5025-6-2-1-0"
       x="82.288353"
       y="920.41907"
       style="font-size:32px">TEXT TO CHANGE</tspan></text>
   ...
  </g>
 </svg>
```

I tried using xml.etree.ElementTree didn't get to the TEXT TO CHANGE...
I also tried

```
from xml.dom as minidom
doc = minidom.parse('File.svg')
text = [text.getAttribute('id') for text in doc.getElementsByTagName('text')
```

but i didn't get to the TEXT TO CHANGE...

how can I alter the text

Comment: The `text` expression is missing a right bracket!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TEXT TO CHANGE is in tspan tag

```
import xml.dom.minidom
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse('File.svg')
name = doc.getElementsByTagName('tspan')
for t in name:
   if (t.attributes['id'].value=="tspan5025-6-2-1-0"):
    print [x.nodeValue for x in t.childNodes]
```

Comment: As there are more than one `text` block I changed it to  
  
  
`for t in name:`  
`print(t.childNodes[0].nodeValue)`  
  
is there a way to adress the `ID` of the text block or the tspan block as i like to change a specific value?  sorry the bad formatting, but i'm struggling with it ...

Comment: `for t in name:`  
      `if (t.attributes['id].value=="tspan5003"):`  
        `t.childNodes[0].nodeValue = '100'`  

I used this to change the value and now how to write it back to the file? I actually can get no clue out of the docu at [https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.dom.minidom.html](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

Comment: got it `f.write(doc.toprettyxml())` thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 5):

Never ignore the possibilities inherent in **brute force**.

```
>>> open('newfile.svg', 'w').write(open('temp.svg').read().replace('>TEXT TO CHANGE</tspan>','>What I meant to write</tspan>'))
```

Result:

[image: altered business card]

Comment: good point but the text i like to change is not always the same so I can not search for it like that. i should better search for the id of the text block an alter the whole tspan block

Answer (score 3):

just to summarize

```
import xml.dom.minidom
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse('d:\\Temp\\heizung.svg')
f = open("d:\\Temp\\heizung.svg", "w")
name = doc.getElementsByTagName('tspan')

name[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = '100'

f.write(doc.toprettyxml())
```